# Securing scrapyd's APIs and Web Interface

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I have setup [Scrapyd](http://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html) to manage Scrapy spiders in a better way and it is doing that really fine. I am just doubtful about how to secure it as I fear anyone who gets to know that this is a Scrapyd server can use the APIs to manipulate the working of scrapyd.

I need only one external IP to be able to interact with the Scrapyd API, no other system should be able to get to it.

How do I secure the server so that not everyone can interact with it?

I could not find anything on Google. Sorry if this is a foolish question, but I really failed to figure it out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done easily with an nginx/htpasswd over ubuntu, for example:

```
apt-get install nginx
apt-get install apache2-utils
```

1) Configure nginx to proxy request from port 80 to port 6800

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
        proxy_send_timeout 300s;
        proxy_read_timeout 300s;
        proxy_pass http://this.is.your.ip:6800/;

        auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    }
}
```

2) Create a new user/pass

```
htpasswd -c /etc/nginx/.htpasswd myuser
```

2b) Reload

```
/etc/init.d/nginx restart
```

3) Configure firewall to drop external access to port 6800

```
ufw default deny incoming
ufw allow ssh
ufw default allow outgoing
ufw allow 80
ufw enable
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a scrapyd problem, That's a server management problem. What you need to do is close the scrapyd port on your server from outside ips except your own.